# Calling javascript Function from HTML with multiple parameters

Tags: javascript, php, html, parameters

I'm trying to call a javascript function called confirmRemove(title, id) to remove an element from a table. This function should be called when the user clicks on a link that looks like an "X". I attached my code below to show how I went about doing this, but I'm seeming to be having some errors and I'm not sure why. Most of the elements are able to be removed, but for a few when I click the link to call the function, nothing happens. Is there a better way of doing this? Not sure why this would happen.

```
<td><?php echo '<a onclick="confirmRemove(\'' . $title . '\',\'' . $id . '\')" 
href="javascript:void(0)">X</a>';?></td>
```

Answer (score 4):

You can try this code

```
<td> <a onclick="confirmRemove('<?php echo $title; ?>','<?php echo $id; ?>')" 
   href="javascript:void(0)">X</a></td>
```

Answer (score 1):

You asked if there is a better way of doing this - I would suggest that there is and that it is to use  an externally registered event handler bound to the specific HTML elements in question - notably a hyperlink in this example.

If you assign relevant attributes to the hyperlink ( dataset attributes are very useful for this sort of task ) you can process them within your event listener very easily. There is not need for complicated `escaping` for quotes by adopting this approach and best of all you can separate HTML from Javascript - the event handlers can be in another file

```
<td>
    <a class='removal' href='javascript:void(0)' data-title="<?php echo $title;>" data-id="<?php echo $id;?>">X</a>
</td>


<script>
    Array.from( document.querySelectorAll('a.removal') ).forEach( a=>{
        a.addEventListener('click',function(e){
            confirmRemove( this.dataset.title, this.dataset.id )
        });
    });
</script>
```